# CSS fluid vertical layout

Tags: css

How can I write a CSS layout like this?

```
+---------+
| header  |
+---------+
|         |
| fill    |
|         |
+---------+
```

where:

- the whole layout spans the entire window
- 'header' and 'fill' are two div, one below the other
- 'header' does *not* have a fixed height (its content may change)
- 'fill' fills up all the remaining space left by 'header', and resizes when 'header' resizes

I thought it was a simple solution, but can't get my head around it.

Thanks

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? If you feel the question is not clear, ask for clarification. If you feel it is not constructive, please explain why (this is a legitimate CSS styling question). If you feel it is a repeat, please link to an existing question that answers this question.

Comment: +1 simple question takes more time to solve. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css fluid layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306844/css-fluid-layout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is similar to the CSS necessary for a "sticky footer", in that you want to fill all the remaining vertical space, but still allow it to grow as necessary. There are a lot of tricky solutions, but most are not supported by IE before version 8 (that's when [`display: table;`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) became possible in IE).

Here's a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/jrcgz/)** of a sticky footer solution I put together a while back, and the necessary jQuery code to make the layout work in IE7. If you don't need IE7 support, just leave out the Javascript code. Since you don't need the footer for your particular case, just leave out the footer element as well. And finally :-p The `#header` element is given a fixed height in the CSS. Remove the line `height: 70pt;` from the CSS to make the header height variable.

In the near future, the [CSS Flexible Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) model will make this kind of layout much easier, but browser support is still very minimal at this moment. Until it becomes more widely available, I recommend using the `display: table;` formatting instead.

Comment: Flexible Box looks promising. I hope it will be supported soon by all major browsers

Answer (score 1):

so you are going to start off with a container

```
<div id="contain">
</div>
```

Then we are going to add the header and footer and styling

```
<div id="contain">
   <div id="header">
      Content from Header
   </div>
   <div id="fill">
      Content from Fill
   </div>
</div>
#contain {
width:100%;
}
#header{
width:100%;
}
#fill{
width:100%;
min-height:100px;
}
```

The fill will automatically adjust itself to the height of the header

http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/gWkm8/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get the content to span the rest of the window apart from the header, instead make the body cover the window, style that, and let your content be a variable size.

I set up a simple jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xeP5M/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="fill">
        this is where content goes        
    </div>
</div>​
```

and the CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
div { width: 100%; }

#container { background: #ff0; min-height: 100%; position: relative; }
#header { background: #f0f; height: 200px; }
#fill { background: #0f0; min-height: 100%; }
```

Cheers.

​